# Chartjs not showing chart

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, chart.js

Here is my view, where I'm trying to render chart:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="bower_components/Chart.js/Chart.js" language="javascript"></script><div><canvas id="countries" width="600" height="400"></canvas></div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="width:75%;">{!! $chart->container() !!}
</div>
```

My controller, with the most simple test example:

```
$chart = new CandidatesAgeChart;
$chart->labels(['2 days ago', 'Yesterday', 'Today']);
$chart->dataset('My dataset', 'line', [$variable1, $variable2, $variable3]);

return view('chart', compact('chart'));
```

and lastly, CandidateAgeChart, left as created.

```
<?php

namespace App\Charts;

use ConsoleTVs\Charts\Classes\Chartjs\Chart;

class CandidatesAgeChart extends Chart
{
    /**
     * Initializes the chart.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

When I go to this specific view, chart is not being shown. I'm not sure what exactly I need to amend in order to get this to work, and documentation did not gave me the answer. [image: loading chart but not rendered]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add {!! $chart->script() !!} to your view.

Comment: I believe i tried that and it didn't work. However I will try again later and let you know.